# Insert bootstrap buttons dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-table

How can I insert, edit and delete bootstrap buttons dynamically on this table in each cell of "Azioni" column?

Then the buttons should open a modal to edit or delete one or more cell on a selected row.

I have tried many times but I failed.

### MY CODE

```
   <!doctype html>

<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js ">
   </script>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js "></script>
   <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js " integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM " crossorigin="anonymous "></script>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js "></script>
   <script src="prova.js " script></script>

</head>

<body>
   <div id="tabella-utenti">
       <table data-toggle="table" data-url="employee_data.json" data-pagination="true" data-search="true" class="table table-borderless table-dark">
           <thead>
               <tr>
                   <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
                   <th data-sortable="true " data-field="idUser">Id User</th>
                   <th data-sortable="true " data-field="email">Email</th>
                   <th data-sortable="true" data-field="name">Name</th>
                   <th data-sortable="true " data-field="surname">Cognome</th>
                   <th data-sortable="true " data-field="is_deleted">Is Deleted</th>
                   <th data-sortable="true"> Azioni</th>
               </tr>
           </thead>
       </table>
   </div>
</body>

<html>
```

Comment: Where is your button code? like JavaScript, buttons?

Comment: I'll take a bootstrap button or something else, I wanted to understand how add the buttons dynamically in each row of the "Azioni" column

Comment: Show what JavaScript you have tried and what your challenge is with that.

Comment: Also please show an example of your JSON object that is being used here

Comment: I am not home at the moment, the json looks like this.

[{
        "idUser": 1,
        "email": "blabla",
        "name": "bla",
        "surname": "blabla",
        "is_deleted": "N"
    },
    {
        "idUser": 2,
        "email": "aaaa",
        "name": "aaaa",
        "surname": "aaaa",
        "is_deleted": "Y"
    },
]

I can't show the output because i'm away from home, I would like to insert two buttons in all cell in the column "Azioni"

Answer (score 1):

Use AJAX to get data from JSON file you used. [help link](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)
Try jQuery each loop

```
$('#table_id tr').each(function(){
   var tr_object = this;
   $(this +' td:last').html('<button type="button" onclick="delete_action('+tr_object+')">Delete</button>');
});

function delete_action(tr_object){
     //perform delete task
}
```

Comment: The table is populated correctly with json, the problem is add two buttons in the cell of the column"Azioni"

Comment: This adds to the table `<thead>`, no really what the OP is asking for I believe

Comment: @Kageyama then you have to use the first code snippet within
`$(document).ready(function(){
//$('#table_id tr').each(function(){ .... });
});`

Answer (score 0):

here you are showing us just the head of the table and not the body.Probably for the body you are taking data from somewhere. So If you have an array of data, you could loop through it and document. `createElement('button').className(Your bootstrap classname')`

Comment: Yes,  i use a json for populate it, but the buttons should only go in the "Azioni" column